# How to include xml documentation in nuget package azure devops? [dotnet core]

Tags: azure-devops

I have created a pipeline to build, pack and push my package to a feed on my Azure DevOps instance.

When I pack using visual studio, it uses
{ABSOLUTE FILE PATH}
As defined in my CSPROJ.

But when I include the package I built through Azure in a project I dont get my documention.

Is there a setting I am missing on Azure which governs Documentation Files, or must the  be relatively pathed to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want to include the xml document generated by the build into the nuget package? If so, you only need to add `GenerateDocumentationFile` attribute in csproj:`<GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>` , so that the XML documentation is included in the package .

[image]

[image]

[image]

If you want to specify an additional xml document to be included in the nuget package, you can refer to the following code:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="..\colors.xml">
        <Pack>true</Pack>
        <PackagePath>content\any\any\;contentFiles\any\any\;;</PackagePath>
        <IncludeInPackage>true</IncludeInPackage>
        <CopyToOutput>true</CopyToOutput>
        <BuildAction>Content</BuildAction>
        <CopyToOutput>true</CopyToOutput>
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        <CopyToPublicDirectory>Always</CopyToPublicDirectory>
    </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I will give this a whirl!

Comment: Thanks! Here's some docs for the flag https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props#generatedocumentationfile